# Зачем нужен Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-apps

Почитал в интернете, но так и не понял, что он из себя представляет и какова сфера его применения. Для взаимодействия с сервером использую Node.js для клиента jQuery. Но в каждой второй вакансии обязательно знание Ангуляра, а значит, что зачем-то он таки нужен.
Собственно вопрос, как лично вы на практике используете Ангуляр и в чём заключается его важность и незаменимость ?

Объяснения из вкипедий, аля "для построения одностраничных веб-приложений" вообще ни о чём мне не говорят.

Comment: Ангуляр, как и любая другая библиотека на JS, нужен для упрощения разработки на JS, всё что он умеет вы можете сделать на чистом JS или на jQuery, но с помощью Angular или, например, Backbone это будет проще, вот и всё. И да, он очень хорош, когда нужно без перезагрузки страницы сделать много разного функционала, это явление википедия и называет SPA

Comment: Ангуляр это вчерашний день, jQuery это позавчерашний день.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, Angular это слишком 2015, да? Не выдумывайте

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На счет ангуляра в вакансиях — это на самом деле очень смешно. В моём опыте был очень забавный случай, когда меня пригласили устраиваться на работу, где в требованиях был Angular. Работодатель мне и говорит:

> — Мы тут разрабатываем сайты на битриксе нашим клиентам
>
> — Одностраничные?
>
> — Зачем? Ты что не знаешь что такое битрикс? Многостраничные, конечно
>
> — Подождите, какие сайты, какой битрикс? У вас в вакансии было написано знание angular js
>
> — А ты что, не знаешь? Ну ничего, научим

Angular сейчас — достаточно модный MVC-фреймворк, как и сам паттерн MVC в вебе. И довольно часто в требования его просто приписывают работодатели глядя на вакансии других компаний, не задумываясь. Нет, конечно, множество компаний использует его осознанно и поэтому требуют.

Любой фреймфорк или библиотека существует для одного: что бы разработчик не сошел с ума в написании кода. Если сравнивать Angular и jQuery, то они сделаны для разных целей и использовать их, соответственно нужно в разных ситуациях.

**jQuery** — библиотека, т.е. набор возможностей для разработки. jQuery был создан для облегчения взаимодействия с DOM документа посредством запросов, похожих на css-селекторы и в дальнейшем развился в толстую библиотеку. Но в нынешних реалиях существуют одностраничные приложения, в которых происходит очень много запросов в DOM и использовать jQuery для создания архитектуры такого приложения — нерационально, иначе придётся делать крепкую оптимизацию взаимодействия в DOM'ом, что усложнит код, и не сильно его ускорит.

**Angular** это фреймворк, т.е. он предоставляет фундамент для веб-разработки. В одностраничных приложениях он может оказаться очень кстати, и упрощает это самое взаимодействие с DOM'ом, потому что, грубо говоря, часть его кода находится в самом html-документе. Лично моё отношение к такому подходу больше отрицательное, чем положительное, хоть и MVC люблю. Но это скорее дело вкуса. Для одностраничных приложений я использую React (еще одна модная библиотека), который кстати, сейчас так же требуют в вакансиях (вместе с Angular и jQuery, ага)

Answer (score 2):

Каждый хочет откусить кусок интернета.
Можно не использовать вообще библиотек и построить приложение своей мечты. Но велосипеды будут как ни крути.
Библиотеки/фрейворки облегчают построение приложения до уровня "лего" или даже проще.

Ангуляр ориентирован на SPA (одностраничных приложений), т. е. загрузка страницы будет один раз, дальше всё (переходы внутри приложения, загрузка данных, рендер и пр.) происходит без перезагрузок (в идеале, конечно).
Выходит, пользоваться им надо именно в SPA, ведь мы не будем выбирать гаубицу для открытия консервы?

---

Что до вакансий - есть куча мест, где пишут что "требуется знание библиотеки Vanilla JS" (для тех, кто не знает - ванильным JS называют нативный JS, no library, no framework).
Т. е. их составляют рандомные личности, которые ничего не понимают в том, кого именно они ищут.
Как следствие, собеседование будет проводить такой же знаток, а компании либо нет денег чтобы грамотного менеджера нанять, либо им плевать. Идти туда не нужно.

Конечно, мозг никто не отменял, вдруг обилие технологий из-за того, что ведётся разработка на всём, что наклепали разные деятели. Опять же, когда ищут "мастера на все библиотеки" вместо спеца в области - это настораживает.